# jQuery call model by clicking on label

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement a feature when a user click on a label a modal pop up.

**Problem**

- I can't open using a Label element, but if i use a button (with the same code) it works.
- if i remove the comment on the hello, i can see the alert (so the code enter on the jquery statement

This is my code (just a code from the bootstrap site)

**HTML**

```
<label id="some-label">Something</label>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#some-label').on('click', function() {
     //alert("hello"); 
     $('#myModal').show();        
 });
```

Comment: Take a closer look at the example. When the modal shows something else changes on the `<div class="modal fade" id="myModal"...`-Element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you're bypassing the standard bootstrap logic for showing the modal. You're calling `show()`, but the element is still set to `opacity: 0` due to the `fade` class, hence nothing is displayed.

To fix this, use the appropriate `data` attributes on the trigger element (`data-target` and `data-toggle`). Then you don't need to include any explicit JS as Bootstrap will do the heavy lifting for you:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<label id="some-label" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Something</label>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ahh.. dumb error. You are right. @Rory McCrossan thank you, you save me :)